# What is the meaning of "blinkers on and a case of Red Bull"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

One of my developer wrote to me in chat,

> please tell LK that you need your blinkers on and a case of Red Bull.

(Here LK is the name of my senior.)

What does "need blinkers on and a case of Red Bull" mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Blinkers](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blinker?q=blinkers) are eye-shades for horses which allow them to see only straight ahead and prevent them from being distracted by events around them.

[Red Bull](http://www.redbull.co.uk/cs/Satellite/en_UK/Red-Bull-Energy-Drink/001243026254412) is a proprietary energy drink.

Your developer is saying that you will need to be focused on the single goal without distractions, and will be working long hours.

Comment: It’s an amusing phrase, I have to give them that.