# How would you name somebody that ignores something just because it's more comfortable or in their interest not to know it?

Tags: single-word-requests

e.g. imagine somebody is looking for an apartment and needs it from September. They see a post somewhere that says "Crazy cool apartment available from August" and they just ignore the fact that it says "from August". 
So when asked "Are you going to take this from August?" they just reply "Oh no I need it from September".

Is there a word for such a behaviour? I can't think of any in either english, italian, spanish or french. Even if you a slovakian word for it, I'd be really interested in it!

Comment: 'Turn a blind eye'?

Answer (score 2):

#### (Bury your) Head in the sand

> Refusal to confront or acknowledge a problem.

**It originates from the supposed habit of ostriches hiding when faced with attack by predators.**

The story was first recorded by the Roman writer Pliny the Elder, who suggested that ostriches hide their heads in bushes. Ostriches don't hide, either in bushes or sand, although they do sometimes lie on the ground to make themselves inconspicuous. The 'burying their head in the sand' myth is likely to have originated from people observing them lowering their heads when feeding.

Source: [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/80800.html)

Comment: This is actually not really close to my example. These people are not avoiding any contact, they just blatantly ignore some facts just because they're focused on their goal. Indirectly, it's a lack of common sense.

Comment: See my other answer.  I've separated them, since they are [two different solutions to the same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105798/what-use-does-add-another-answer-button-have).

Answer (score 0):

another option could be:

#### (Be) Wearing blinkers

> to be able only to see things one way and unwilling or unable to consider other possibilities

As [Andrew Leach♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18696/andrew-leach) says [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97248/194281),

> Blinkers are eye-shades for horses which allow them to see only straight ahead and prevent them from being distracted by events around them.

This expression can have both positive and negative connotations, so if you accuse someone of having blinkers on, you *accuse them of being narrow-minded*.  Be warned: having blinkers on isn't only bad, as it could also describe concentrating and ignoring distractions.

Comment: Is blinkers a separate term from blinders or is this a misnomer?

Comment: @PV22 It's the same term, although I've never heard of 'blinders' before. Is it AmE?

Comment: Perhaps that's the difference. I have never heard of blinkers in AmE

Comment: @PV22 I'm not American, I was wondering if it was...